# Filter value in a CSV via egrep

Tags: linux, grep

I have a CSV file which needs to separate values into separate CSV file.

It already has an existing code:\

1. First sub file needs a file that contains value in first and second fields

   `egrep "^[^,]+,[^,]+," orig.csv > suba.csv`
2. Second sub contains files containing values in first but empty in the second

   `egrep "^[^,]+,," orig.csv > subb.csv`

From what I understand the `^[^,]+,` means must start with a value but the value must not be a comma then followed by a comma.

We have a new requirement that the fifth column must not be a blank:

Here is what I thought it should be but unfortunately it still receives the value with the fifth column with no value

```
egrep "^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+" orig.csv > suba_2.csv
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data?  Do you have trailing whitespace?  Are you processing this in unix, but the text file was generated in Windows?  If that's the case, you may have an extra Ctrl-M at the end of every line.

Comment: @Graham - excellent point; you may be the only one who has actually answered the OP's question correctly rather than simply come up with an alternate solution or workaround.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
egrep "^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^, ]+" orig.csv
```

I am suspecting there is whitespace in your fifth element.

Your regex worked for me with the following input:

```
% cat orig.csv
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,
% egrep "^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+" orig.csv
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5
%
```

But not when I put a space at the end of the last line 1,2,3,4, .

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use `awk`?

```
$ awk -F, '{out="subb.csv"} $2{out="suba.csv"} $5{print > out}' orig.csv
```

**How does this work?**

Let's break it down:

- `-F,` sets the delimiter to a comma.
- `{out="subb.csv"}` sets a default output file.
- `$2{out="suba.csv"}` tests the second field. If it's not empty, sets a different output file.
- `$5{print > out}` tests whether the fifth field is empty, and if it's not, prints the output to whatever output file was specified earlier.

Note that these simple "empty" tests are not exactly fool-proof.  If a field is "0", it will evaluate to false.  If your data may contain a field that is "0" but must be evaluated as true, then this script can be adapted (lengthened) to account for that.